# copy paste one single value multiple times to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Column "ID" starting from Column C3 in sheet1 where all the id's are listed with an interval of 4 blank cells between each unique id's, as shown below

[image]

I want to copy the id's and paste it to Sheet2 five times as shown below

[image]

Can anyone sugggest how can i get this automated with the help of VBA

Comment: Your narrative states that the IDs start in C3 yet your image shows them starting in Row1. Given this obvious disparity, it is impossible to determine where on Sheet2 you want the IDs to be placed.

Comment: ..oh sorry it was an honest mistake it starts in row 1 many thanks to point it out.. i want the id's to be placed in "sheet2" B2 ...

Answer (score 1):

Put this formula in Sheet2!B2,

```
=vlookup("zzzz", sheet1!C$3:C3, 1)
```

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: many thanks, but i need this to be accomplished with the help of vba code, this is much a small part of a bigger process of simplyfying the data, and the tabular result is detrimental for the rest of the process, and hence need automated process for it..... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Sub copyCell()

    Dim idColumn As String
    Dim startRow, lastRow, row As Integer

    Dim sht1, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Setting sheet1
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Setting sheet1

    idColumn = "C" 'Setting column id value column

    startRow = 1 'Setting the start row from sheet 1

    'Getting the last used row from sheet 1
    lastRow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, rowColumn).End(xlUp).row

    For row = startRow To lastRow Step 1

        'Check Id Value is empty or not
        If sht1.Range(idColumn & row) <> "" Then
            'If not empty, set value
            sht2.Range(idColumn & row) = sht1.Range(idColumn & row)
        Else
            'If empty, set value from previous row of sheet 2
            sht2.Range(idColumn & row) = sht2.Range(idColumn & (row - 1))
        End If

    Next row

End Sub
```

I already tested my code with your sample data. It works well for me.

I believe that will be helpful for you.